# Splitting this CSV file into a list

Tags: python, csv, split

So I want to read in a csv file in Python3 and split it into a list. Where each `index[0,1, ..., onwards]` relates to each value separated by comma.
This is my csv file:

```
2017-04-1,14.9,30.1,0,8.2,10.8,NE,33,11:55,20.3,51,0,E,11,1023.9,29.5,25,0,ENE,7,1020.3
,2017-04-2,17.4,31.6,0,8.0,10.9,NE,35,08:56,23.5,34,0,NE,17,1021.4,30.7,20,0,SE,9,1018.6
2017-04-3,12.1,31.8,0,6.8,10.8,SSW,33,15:14,23.1,39,0,SSE,6,1022.7,29.3,34,0,SSW,19,1020.8
,2017-04-4,15.4,30.4,0,7.0,10.7,E,28,03:01,19.8,64,0,ESE,11,1024.9,29.7,29,0,S,9,1020.3
,2017-04-5,12.3,30.4,0,5.2,10.6,S,19,13:10,21.7,55,0,NE,6,1018.2,27.7,37,0,WSW,11,1013.5
,2017-04-6,13.7,24.4,0,5.2,8.1,SW,43,16:16,17.1,94,7,NE,2,1013.1,22.8,63,3,SSW,20,1011.7
,2017-04-7,14.8,22.3,0,5.4,8.9,SSE,35,06:26,16.4,56,5,SSE,17,1023.6,21.3,33,3,SSE,4,1021.6
,2017-04-8,8.7,23.6,0,5.0,10.5,SW,33,15:41,16.0,58,0,SE,7,1027.6,22.1,44,0,SW,17,1024.5
,2017-04-9,11.1,27.4,0,4.8,10.4,ESE,24,10:30,18.1,56,0,ENE,13,1027.4,26.8,26,0,NE,9,1023.1
,2017-04-10,10.0,30.1,0,5.6,10.4,SSW,24,16:38,19.3,51,4,E,9,1022.7,30.0,20,1,E,6,1018.4
,2017-04-11,13.1,28.1,0,6.6,10.5,SW,28,15:02,21.8,38,0,NE,9,1016.6,26.6,35,0,SW,13,1015.7
,2017-04-12,10.6,23.8,0,5.2,9.7,SW,35,16:19,17.4,69,6,ENE,9,1021.5,23.0,52,1,SW,15,1019.9
,2017-04-13,12.9,26.8,0,4.2,10.4,SSW,31,15:56,19.9,64,1,ESE,11,1024.3,25.5,49,1,SW,15,1020.1
,2017-04-14,12.8,29.0,0,5.8,6.2,SW,22,15:43,18.1,73,4,SSE,2,1019.3,27.6,42,5,SSW,11,1015.4
,2017-04-15,14.8,29.3,0,4.0,7.3,SSE,31,22:03,18.5,73,6,S,11,1015.7,28.2,38,7,SE,9,1011.7
,2017-04-16,17.2,25.1,0,5.4,7.0,SSE,35,00:43,18.8,66,4,ESE,11,1014.6,24.4,54,5,SW,11,1011.6
,2017-04-17,15.4,21.8,0,5.0,2.5,SSW,24,07:56,17.8,74,5,S,13,1015.3,21.4,59,8,SSW,11,1013.2
,2017-04-18,15.3,25.0,0,4.0,8.0,SSW,31,19:02,19.7,72,6,SSE,9,1013.0,22.8,63,1,SW,15,1010.4
```

Currently when I read it in, each element is being split at the end of the line. So if I accessed `index[0]` this would be the output.

```
2017-04-1,14.9,30.1,0,8.2,10.8,NE,33,11:55,20.3,51,0,E,11,1023.9,29.5,25,0,ENE,7,1020.3
```

What I need to understand is how to split the csv so that if I access `index[0]`, I will be given 2017-04-1. And `index[1]` would give the next value after the comma.

Here is my code at the moment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Opening and reading files
weatherdata = open('weather.csv', encoding='latin1')
data = weatherdata.readlines()
```

Encoding is required to be in latin one because it needs to be able to handle degree symbols.

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You have already read all lines into data:

```
weatherdata = open('weather.csv')
data = weatherdata.readlines()
data
```

data will be a string list:

```
['2017-04-1,14.9,30.1,0,8.2,10.8,NE,33,11:55,20.3,51,0,E,11,1023.9,29.5,25,0,ENE,7,1020.3\n',
 '2017-04-2,17.4,31.6,0,8.0,10.9,NE,35,08:56,23.5,34,0,NE,17,1021.4,30.7,20,0,SE,9,1018.6 \n',
 '2017-04-3,12.1,31.8,0,6.8,10.8,SSW,33,15:14,23.1,39,0,SSE,6,1022.7,29.3,34,0,SSW,19,1020.8\n',
 '2017-04-4,15.4,30.4,0,7.0,10.7,E,28,03:01,19.8,64,0,ESE,11,1024.9,29.7,29,0,S,9,1020.3\n',
 '2017-04-5,12.3,30.4,0,5.2,10.6,S,19,13:10,21.7,55,0,NE,6,1018.2,27.7,37,0,WSW,11,1013.5\n',
 '2017-04-6,13.7,24.4,0,5.2,8.1,SW,43,16:16,17.1,94,7,NE,2,1013.1,22.8,63,3,SSW,20,1011.7\n',
 '2017-04-7,14.8,22.3,0,5.4,8.9,SSE,35,06:26,16.4,56,5,SSE,17,1023.6,21.3,33,3,SSE,4,1021.6\n',
 '2017-04-8,8.7,23.6,0,5.0,10.5,SW,33,15:41,16.0,58,0,SE,7,1027.6,22.1,44,0,SW,17,1024.5\n',
 '2017-04-9,11.1,27.4,0,4.8,10.4,ESE,24,10:30,18.1,56,0,ENE,13,1027.4,26.8,26,0,NE,9,1023.1\n',
 '2017-04-10,10.0,30.1,0,5.6,10.4,SSW,24,16:38,19.3,51,4,E,9,1022.7,30.0,20,1,E,6,1018.4\n',
 '2017-04-11,13.1,28.1,0,6.6,10.5,SW,28,15:02,21.8,38,0,NE,9,1016.6,26.6,35,0,SW,13,1015.7\n',
 '2017-04-12,10.6,23.8,0,5.2,9.7,SW,35,16:19,17.4,69,6,ENE,9,1021.5,23.0,52,1,SW,15,1019.9\n',
 '2017-04-13,12.9,26.8,0,4.2,10.4,SSW,31,15:56,19.9,64,1,ESE,11,1024.3,25.5,49,1,SW,15,1020.1\n',
 '2017-04-14,12.8,29.0,0,5.8,6.2,SW,22,15:43,18.1,73,4,SSE,2,1019.3,27.6,42,5,SSW,11,1015.4\n',
 '2017-04-15,14.8,29.3,0,4.0,7.3,SSE,31,22:03,18.5,73,6,S,11,1015.7,28.2,38,7,SE,9,1011.7\n',
 '2017-04-16,17.2,25.1,0,5.4,7.0,SSE,35,00:43,18.8,66,4,ESE,11,1014.6,24.4,54,5,SW,11,1011.6\n',
 '2017-04-17,15.4,21.8,0,5.0,2.5,SSW,24,07:56,17.8,74,5,S,13,1015.3,21.4,59,8,SSW,11,1013.2\n',
 '2017-04-18,15.3,25.0,0,4.0,8.0,SSW,31,19:02,19.7,72,6,SSE,9,1013.0,22.8,63,1,SW,15,1010.4']
```

Then use `data[0].split(',')[0]`, it will give you:

```
'2017-04-1'
```

and `data[0].split(',')[1]`, will be:

```
'14.9'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read and then split:

```
weatherdata = open('weather.csv')
data = [line.split(',') for line in weatherdata.read().splitlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try that. Didn't know you could do it that way.

Comment: I tried it that way but it is still giving me the same line when accessing index[0]

Comment: Just use `index[0][0]` then, since it is a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use pandas and it does it for you,[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is very useful to read dataset and manipulate them,it reads the data all at once and you can get different columns after reading them

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('weather.csv')
df.column[0]# this will get the first column
```